# PHP Exec SCP does not copy the file to the remote server

Tags: php, exec, scp

I need a file from a server to another server (I own both) using PHP. I have the following script:

```
<?php

exec('scp /home/pat/file1.tst pat@myserver.com:/home/pat/file1.txt');
```

I get this error:

```
Disallowed system call: SYS_pipe
```

What is that error? and how can I fix it?

Comment: I hate to be captain obvious here, but `SYS_pipe` is disallowed, and to fix the error, you need to allow it.

Comment: First hit on Google was this SO comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964766/ensuring-user-input-code-does-not-damage-server-when-executed - so it's likely an prohibited exec. Btw, see [ssh2_scp_send](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php) as alternative.

Comment: @Cyclone: Here here ... You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. I seem to be Captain Obvious :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP environment does not allow exec on your server.

Comment: and how can I enable it? do I need to update the apache? or php?

Comment: if it is your server check php.ini disable_functions ... if it is a hosted server tough noogies I'll bet my pension they won't enable it.

Answer (score 2):

This is kinda late, I know, but you might have better luck with [phpseclib's pure PHP SCP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net):

https://raw.github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/master/phpseclib/Net/SCP.php

Example of how to use it:

```
<?php
include('Net/SCP.php');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('bad login');
}

$scp = new Net_SCP($ssh);
$scp->put('abcd', str_repeat('x', 1024*1024));
?>
```