# Problem to download binary file using phpseclib SCP

Tags: php, download, scp, phpseclib

I have a a small PHP script that uses [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/index.html) to download files from remote server.

The script is like below:

```
    include('Net/SCP.php');
    echo var_dump($ssh->exec('whoami')); // debug to test the ssh connection. returns "myuser"
    $scp = new Net_SCP($ssh);
    try{
        $remotePath = '/home/user/test.txt';
        $localPath = '/tmp/myfile';
        if (!$scp->get($remotePath, $localPath)) {
            throw new Exception("Problems to get file");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "\n\n" . var_dump($e->getMessage()) . "\n\n";die;
    }
```

There are some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308449/3943162) questions here in SO that uses very similar snippets.
It works like a charm for many files, but it fails for some binary files (`$remotePath = '/home/user/test.p12';`, for instance).

Are there any know limitation to download binary files using phpseclib (I didn't find anything in [their issues on github](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues?q=scp%20download))? If not, what I'm doing wrong? Am I forgetting some options or anything?

As a side note `scp myuser@serverip:/home/user/test.p12 /tmp/teste.p12` works fine in command line.

Following the comments, I must indicate that my script just fails. The statment `$scp->get($remotePath, $localPath` returns false for all binary files that I tried. Thats all i have for now.
As far as I know, phpseclib does not have any detailed log on these fails.

My application log (nginx) does not show anything special. Access log on my remote server (centOS. for these tests I have the control over it, but its not the real scenario) I got something like below:

```
Jul 27 15:22:58 localhost sshd[14101]: Accepted password for myuser from myip port 51740 ssh2
Jul 27 15:22:58 localhost sshd[14101]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user myuser by (uid=0)
Jul 27 15:22:58 localhost sshd[14103]: Received disconnect from myip port 51740:11:
Jul 27 15:22:58 localhost sshd[14103]: Disconnected from user myuser myip port 51740
```

PHP version: 7.3 (the script is also used in servers with older versions)

Local server: Debian 10

Remote server: CentOs 8

The problematic file that fires the problem is a certificate p12 file.

Comment: "but it fails" more details please.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe your actual problem in more detail. How does it fail? What happens when you run your code? Do you get any error messages? What do they say?

Comment: @Sammitch and Kenster. I tried to include some more information, but I don't have much more.

Comment: I just found the problem. Sometimes, just write down the question and it bring me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and it was much more simple than I tought. It was just a permission problem (for any good reason, I put all my test files in a directory without read permition).

I decided to leave this answer here, because I think that this is not clear on phpseclib documentation, but the 'Net/SCP.php' only works with files with read permission, so, before download make sure that the file are readable or execute something like `chmod o+r filename`.

The snippet in the question works fine with binary files.